# How can I fix my output in my toString method?

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, linked-list, tostring

I am working on a project for my Data Structures class that asks me to write a class to implement a linked list of ints.

> - Use an inner class for the Node.
> - Include the methods below.
> - Write a tester to enable you to test all of the methods with whatever data you want in any order.

I have to create a toString method called "public String toString()". This method is meant to "Print the List but in the format of [1, 2, 3] with the commas and brackets in the right place." I have my code for this method down below. However, when I use the toString method there's a bit of an issue. For example, if I have a list [17, 14, 8, 11, 19, 6, 15, 11, 5, 5]. My output is [17, 14, 8, 11, 19, 6, 15, 11, 5, 5, ]. After the last element, I get an extra comma and an extra space at the end. How do I fix this?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LinkedListOfInts {
    Node head;
    Node tail;

    private class Node {
        int value;
        Node nextNode;

        public Node(int value, Node nextNode) {
            this.value = value;
            this.nextNode = nextNode;
        }

    }

    public LinkedListOfInts(LinkedListOfInts other) {
        Node tail = null;
        for (Node n = other.head; n != null; n = n.nextNode) {
            if (tail == null)
                this.head = tail = new Node(n.value, null);
            else {
                tail.nextNode = new Node(n.value, null);
                tail = tail.nextNode;
            }
        }
    }

    public LinkedListOfInts(int[] other) {
        Node[] nodes = new Node[other.length];
        for (int index = 0; index < other.length; index++) {
            nodes[index] = new Node(other[index], null);
            if (index > 0) {
                nodes[index - 1].nextNode = nodes[index];
            }
        }

        head = nodes[0];
    }

    public LinkedListOfInts(int N, int low, int high) {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            this.addToFront(random.nextInt(high - low) + low);
    }

    public void addToFront(int x) {
        head = new Node(x, head);
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        for (Node ptr = head; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.nextNode)
            result += ptr.value + ", ";
        return "[" + result + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        LinkedListOfInts list = new LinkedListOfInts(10, 1, 20);
        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            System.out.println("1. toString");
            switch (input.nextInt()) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("toString");
                System.out.println(list.toString());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to check if you are at the last node or not: `result += ptr.value + (ptr != tail ? ", " : "");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html), for example...

```
public String toString() {
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", ", "[", "]");;
    for (Node ptr = head; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.nextNode) {
        sj.add(Integer.toString(ptr.value));
    }
    return sj.toString();
}
```

Then using something like...

```
LinkedListOfInts list = new LinkedListOfInts(new int[]{17, 14, 8, 11, 19, 6, 15, 11, 5, 5});
System.out.println(list.toString());
```

Will print...

```
[17, 14, 8, 11, 19, 6, 15, 11, 5, 5]
```

Now, if you can't use a `StringJoiner` , don't append the `,` but prefix it instead, for example...

```
public String toString() {
    String result = "";
    for (Node ptr = head; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.nextNode) {
        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
            result += ", ";
        }
        result += ptr.value;
    }
    return "[" + result + "]";
}
```

We can discuss the important of using a `StringBuilder` and all that as well, but you're getting the idea

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have never used StringBuilder but it looks interesting. However, my Professor would not like that since it's something too advanced. But the second answer choice you gave me works so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the node outside of the loop and iterate until the second to last node by checking if the *next* node is null. Then after the for loop append the last node's value.

i.e.

```
public String toString() {
    String result = "";
    Node ptr;
    for (ptr = head; ptr.nextNode != null; ptr = ptr.nextNode) {
        result += ptr.value + ", ";
    result += ptr.value + "]";
    result = "[" + result;
    return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public String toString() {
    return Stream.iterate(head, Objects::nonNull, Node::nextNode)
        .map(n -> String.valueOf(n.value))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your response. This looks interesting but it's not something my professor would want me to submit as he wants it to be simpler. This might be something I'll learn in the future but thanks anyway.